# How to check if someone is streaming RTP over a specific Multicast address?

Tags: networking, ffmpeg, streaming, multicast

Let's say we have ubuntu machine A with ip 192.168.0.20 and ubuntu machine B with ip 192.168.0.21 in same network. How can I check if machine A is streaming RTP to a multicast address and port for example

```
239.0.0.1:5005
```

in machine B?

Comment: What have you tried to get the desired result? Are you familiar at all with the linux command-line utilities `ss` and `tcpdump`? If not, I'd suggest looking at their manual pages for more information (`man ss` and `man tcpdump`).

Answer (score 1):

In an environment where IP multicast isn't simply flooded to all ports of a dumb switch, using `tcpdump` alone would likely capture no traffic: the switch snooping IGMP reports and queries (or doing itself queries) seeing there is no need for this multicast traffic on machine B's port would just not send it. This *also* requires a multicast client that used `setsockopt(fd, SOL_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, ...)` on its socket.

Install `socat` and use:

```
socat -d -d -u udp4-recv:5005,reuseaddr,ip-add-membership=239.0.0.1:192.168.0.21 /dev/null
```

this will:

- join the multicast group 239.0.0.1 on the interface with 192.168.0.21 by sending an initial IGMP membership report, which when processed by an IGMP snooping bridge in presence of a querier will then make the smart switch send traffic to machine B's switch port

  - Optional `reuseaddr` here allows to run multiple times the same command (multicast at the system level then just makes each command receive a copy of the single multicast flow).
  - `-d -d` makes `socat` verbose: it will also display the source of the received packets.
  - Once joined, anything related to 239.0.0.1 can now be captured with `tcpdump`.
  - If 192.168.0.20 is sending to 239.0.0.1, the received packets will have 192.168.0.20 as source showing what system sent it.
- receive the data and forget it to `/dev/null`. If the data is a video stream (really on port 5005, not say 5004), replacing `/dev/null` with `- | mpv -` would display the video using the `mpv` command.

When *socat* is stopped, an IGMP leave message will be sent by the kernel. Depending on switch's settings, it will immediately stop sending this multicast destination to machine B or this will happen within the next minute(s). `tcpdump` might thus continue to capture traffic, but this won't last.

note:

In an environment where the network is handled by a dumb switch (or a virtual linux bridge where the *mcast_querier* toggle is not set) then `tcpdump` would capture the multicast traffic in all cases because the switch is flooding it on all of its ports.